# Odd behavior with Flex header as page size changes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a header on my website which is behaving oddly as I expand and shrink the window size. I have not come across a bug like this before and am not sure if I am overlooking something simple.

It seems that the flex behavior of the header is changing every few pixels — for no apparent reason to me. Reference the attached video: [image: Weird Flex Bug]

Here are two images show the difference in width for for `#nav--logo` when the window width is 1px different.

[image: correct outcome]
[image: odd bug outcome]

Here is the relevant code I have for the header:

```css
body#home-page {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: var(--blue);
    color: var(--red);
    height: 100vh;
}

body#home-page>header {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

body#home-page>#main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

body#home-page>footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

/* Header  */

header {
    display: flex;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
    padding: var(--outer-padding);
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
    color: var(--red);
}

header>.nav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: var(--max-layout-width);
}

header nav {
    align-self: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}

header nav .nav--link {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2.15rem;
}

header #nav--logo {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    height: 100%;
}

header #nav--logo>img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

header #nav--logo>span {
    align-self: center;
}

header #nav--menu {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

header #nav--menu>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 4.75rem;
}
```

```html
<body id="home-page">
    <header>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <nav id="nav--logo">
                <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
            </nav>
            <nav id="nav--menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav--link"><span><a href="work">work</a></span></li>
                    <li class="nav--link"><span><a href="about">about</a></span></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- rest of site below -->
</body>
```

All suggestions are appreciated! Thanks for the help!

FYI: the error in the console is related to my favicon.ico missing.

Comment: this looks like some element is stretching the whole page on resize. doesn't have to be the headers fault. can you try after removing every other element?

Comment: @niorad I tried removing all the other elements from the page but I am still experiencing the same bug.

Comment: @niorad I added two images that show how the header logo width is expanding.

Comment: Would it be possible to host the "real" version somewhere? Not getting the issue in the code-snippet, unfortunately.